# Meteor Login Failed when used from command line

Tags: meteor

I'm using meteor login and receiving Login Failed.

When I sign in to meteor.com using my user/name and password, it works OK.

Does meteor login use a different credential store or is it the same as the website?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hopefully this helps others.

I was using my email and password to sign in to the website and so I thought that would work via meteor login

Apparently I also have a username (seperate to the email address)

I was able to successfully sign in via command line using UserName & Password.

I think it is odd that you can sign into website with Email & Password, but via commandline it is UserName & Password.

Comment: could you tell me where you find your username?

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem.

To find your username, just login to meteor.com and go to 'My Account'.

You will see 'Basic info for **username**' as the heading.

Answer (score 1):

After numerous attempts entering and continually getting "login failed", I decided to change my password to include only lower case characters.   My next attempt at deployment succeeded because it understood my password entry.